# How to use aws transcoder on videos saved in other cms apart from s3 bucket?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I am planning to use aws in my project to encode mp4 to streaming video format. But my videos are not saved in Amazon s3 bucket. When i tried to create pipline i noticed that they are asking s3 bucket name. Is it possible to use aws encoder in this scenario without downloading those videos from other cms to s3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy the files to S3.